# Remote Process Execution using Wmi win32_Process - Getting Stdout of Process

Tags: c#, wmi

Hi i am able to execute a remote process using Wmi and was able to get return Value and Process Id of the Process. Is there any way to get the Output of the Process which was started by Wmi. Eg. If i start an exe which prints something in console will i be able to get those values using this Api. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must redirect the output to a file, then read the file across the network.

Use the CMD.EXE /S /C option to do this.

Example command line to run `Program.exe`:

```
CMD.EXE /S /C " "c:\path\to\program.exe" "argument1" "argument2"  > "c:\path\to\stdout.txt" 2> "c:\path\to\stderr.txt" "
```

Then connect to server like this `\\servername\c$\path\to\stdout.txt` to read the stdout results.

**Note:** Pay careful attention to the extra quotes around the command to run. These are necessary to ensure the command line is interpreted correctly.

Comment: A note to anyone else trying to get output from a WMI `Win32_process` - note the extra quotation marks in the above command! These are very important. Read `cmd.exe /?` for more information about quote handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **psexec** to execute the program.exe and get the stdout by pipe

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while p.poll() is None:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    line = line.strip().decode('gbk')
    if line:
        print('Subprogram output: [{}]'.format(line))
if p.returncode == 0:
    print('Subprogram success')
    return True
else:
    print('Subprogram failed')
    return False
```